# Restore redis data from slave to master

Tags: redis

I need to don't loss any data on redis and It has high write request,so I can't use AOF persistence.RDB can help be,but maybe It's possible to loss some of data from last backup.

Now I think about replication as backup,so when master crashed,restarted or anything else,I have synced data in slaves and can restore it again.

Now is there any way set master as slave,and slave as master at crashed time automatically,then sync them?

Comment: Hey, did you get anwhere with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application comes to know that MASTER is down, application should issue below command on SLAVE:

> SLAVEOF NO ONE

The above command would make the SLAVE as MASTER and your application could continue using this as MASTER now.

When your actual MASTER is up, issue following command:

> SLAVEOF hostname port

Here hostname and port would be for the old SLAVE. With this the MASTER-SLAVE configuration is swapped.