# Redis slave is not responding the data

Tags: redis

```
./redis-cli -c -p 7003 keys '*' | sort -nr | head
20190500210000
20190500200108
20190500200104
20190500200100


./redis-cli -c -p 7000 keys '*' | sort -nr | head
20190500210000
20190500200108
20190500200104
20190500200100
```

Same data is there. 7000 is master. 7003 is slave for 7000.

But when I kill master, slave is returning the below.

```
./redis-cli -c -p 7003 dbsize | sort -nr | head
```

**Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7000: Connection refused**

**Edit:**

```
./redis-cli -p 7000 type 20190405080190

(error) MOVED 1326 127.0.0.1:7003
```

This is second time. 7003 is promoted as master. 7000 became slave after restarting. If I don't specify `-c`, it is throwing error. So data doesn't available in slave node?

```
./redis-cli -c -p 7000 type 20190405080190

set
```

Killed the new master 7003

```
kill -9 23531
```

Connecting to slave to get data:

```
./redis-cli -c -p 7000 type 20190405080190

Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7003: Connection refused

Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7003: Connection refused


./redis-cli -p 7000 type 20190405080190

(error) MOVED 1326 127.0.0.1:7003
```

That's why I confused. It takes some time to promote master. Is it the reason?

Yes, I verified that. It takes some time. Why is it so? Doesn't slave keep data?

Comment: You should see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931013/restore-redis-data-from-slave-to-master). I believe it's relevant.